# Jupyter notebook can't load installed package in conda environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I've created a `conda` environment:

```
$ conda create --name py3 matplotlib scipy astropy photutils
```

Everything installed properly, including the `photutils` package that is installed from the http://ssb.stsci.edu/astroconda channel.

Now I activate the environment and open a Jupyter notebook:

```
$ source activate py3
(py3) $ jupyter notebook
```

With `py3` as the *Default* environments, and `photutils` installed

[image]

I open a new notebook that uses the *Default* kernel and attempt to load `photutils`

[image]

which will not work.

What is going on here? The only thing that I find strange is that the name of the `photutils` package is shown as `http://ssb.stsci.edu/astroconda::photutils0.4` by Jupyter in the `Conda` tab. Is this the issue? If so, how can I fix this?

Comment: I think the `default` kernel is installed in the environment where the Jupyter Notebook is installed. You either need to 1) install the notebook in the `py3` environment, or 2) install the `ipykernel` package in the `py3` notebook and launch the notebook from the root environment, then start a notebook with the `py3` kernel

Comment: I don't follow. Jupyter is being loaded from the `py3` environment, so it is installed in it.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you didn't install the Notebook in the `py3` environment, your shell may still be finding the executable from the root environment, since that environment will still be on your PATH. What is the output of `which jupyter`?

Comment: You are correct. It was picking up `jupyter` from `/home/gabriel/anaconda3/bin/` instead of the  loaded environment. After `conda install jupyter` in the `py3` env (and restarting the terminal session) it now correctly points to `/home/gabriel/anaconda3/envs/py3/bin/` and the package is properly loaded. Could you turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `default` kernel is installed in the environment where the Jupyter Notebook is installed. You either need to either 1) install the `notebook` pacakge in the `py3` environment, or 2) install the `ipykernel` package in the `py3` environment and launch the Notebook server from the root environment, then start a new Notebook with the (now newly added) `py3` kernel.