# Not able to import libraries in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have installed the the library num2words by `pip install num2words` from the command prompt. But when I try to use `num2words` in anaconda jupyter notebook. It says:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'num2words'".

I don't know how to get the external installed library in the jupyter notebook.

Comment: This might help you: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/

Comment: Was the `jupyter`'s environment active, when you issued `pip install num2words`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jupyter notebook can't load installed package in conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47557385/jupyter-notebook-cant-load-installed-package-in-conda-environment)