# plotly cannot be imported from jupyter-notebook even it has been installed

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, plotly, conda

I am trying to use `plotly` in `Jupyter-notebook` under the virtual environment created using `Anaconda`. I have successfully installed plotly, as tested from command line prompt.

[image]

However, when I import plotly in Jupyter-notebook, it failed. What can be the reason?

[image]

Comment: Could you please check the kernal set for the jupyter notebook, it think it may be set to one that does not have plotly installed!

Comment: But there is is only one kernel Python3 from the "change kernel"  manual.

Comment: Did you install either `notebook` or `ipykernel` into your new environment? If not, you need to do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jupyter notebook can't load installed package in conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47557385/jupyter-notebook-cant-load-installed-package-in-conda-environment)

Comment: Could you post the output of " import plotly; plotly.__path__". Also please report the output of "import sys; print (sys.path)" in both the jupyter and python prompt.

Comment: Please also do not post terminal/code output in images. Please see here for why: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/40481