# Installed python package to conda virtual environment, ModuleNotFoundError in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Installed python package from the Anaconda Prompt in the virtual environment.
`import transformers` works from the Anaconda Prompt. However, `ModuleNotFoundError` when in Jupyter Notebook even though kernel is set to the virtual environment where the package is installed.

It looks like the issue is similar to
[Jupyter notebook can't load installed package in conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47557385/jupyter-notebook-cant-load-installed-package-in-conda-environment), but I can't get it to work on Windows.

Here is an example.

[Package is installed in the virtual environment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6fX7.png)

[Importing from the anaconda prompt works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKXwB.png)

[Importing from Jupyter Notebook causes the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJce8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Open the Jupyter notebook from command line. Activate your conda environment first.

1. Open command line. Activate your conda environment.
   Type `activate <your env name>`
2. Type `jupyter notebook <path to your project>`. To open in current directory `jupyter notebook .` .

Comment: Hi! Can you clarify path to what exactly? Thanks!

Comment: Hello. Its path to your project. Or if you want to open it in the current directory just type `jupyter notebook  . `

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the issue. I've added some images above that will hopefully describe the problem better.

Comment: I saw the images. How are you opening the  jupyter notebook ? Do you use command line? is it after activating your env or before?

Comment: I did `jupyter notebook` from the anaconda prompt after I activated the env.

Comment: by anaconda prompt you mean conda command line right? Not the python console you mention in second image. Well then I am stumped :)

Answer (score 0):

The package was initially installed using `conda install -c conda-forge transformers`.

Instead, I installed the packaged using `pip install transformers`. Importing the package from Jupyter Notebook on the virtual environment's kernel worked fine afterwards.

When I did `where conda` from the virtual environment, `conda install` doesn't seem to be installing to the venv. Whereas `where pip` showed that the [venv's pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6yDO.png) is being used.